# S3 front end showing CORS preflight error to an EC2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, http-status-code-503

I've been through all the various [cors] and [s3] error fixes and nothing seems to work.
Hoping someone has an insight into this.

I have a react front end in S3 and its sending and api call to an EC2 server with loadbalancer in front of it. The error I am getting is:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.b3tz.com/api/users/login' from origin 'http://casual-wager- 
prod.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The eventual status code is **Status Code: 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity**

My S3 CORS configuration is:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE",
        "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

ok, so my server was originally setup to add its own responses to any requests and that was failing in pre-fetch. On advice I substituted cors
and am getting the same error, no change in behavior:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join('public')));

/* app.options('/api/users', cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');

  next();
}); */
```

My front end call is so:

```
 const responseData = await sendRequest(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/users/login`,
      'POST',
      JSON.stringify({
        email: formState.inputs.email.value,
        password: formState.inputs.password.value
      }),
      {
        'Origin':'casualwager.com',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
```

This is my production deployed code. The same code deployed to staging works fine.
The difference is staging does not have a loadbalancer in front of its server and the staging S3 has no CORS configuration.

Otherwise I cant see what the problem might be.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would try using the cors package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and seeing if that works in place of your own custom cors middleware and see if that makes a difference and if it does then you can eliminate that it's an issue with your code

Comment: try someything like this http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: @Win I was using cors package before and was still having the problem. There have been a few changes since then however so I will put it back in and see

Comment: Added cors as above edits show. Used both preflight cors options and the generic app.use(cors()), neither one changed the behavior at all.